# Android: How to get my app to open on screen from Broadcast Receiver and alarm

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I want my app to open on screen periodically (even though the docs say it's not recommended) for a cognition experiment.
In the main activity, the user hits a button to schedule the next test, and closes the app. I have the button callback using the `alarmManager` to call a `BroadcastReceiver`, and this appears to be working. I hit the button, close the app, and after X seconds, the receiver makes a sound, and logs.
But I can't get the receiver to force the app open on screen again, the way my alarm clock and stopwatch do. (And I need this, not just a notification, because the user needs taking the test to be as few clicks as possible, they will do it like 50 times a day...) The weird thing is if I don't close the app after hitting the button to schedule, then I *do* see the app be restarted: the screen redraws itself, and my log statement from `onCreate` runs.
But if I've closed it after hitting the button, I hear the sound running in the receiver, but my app does not open on screen. It seems like the receiver only gets to wake the Main activity if the activity is already open in the foreground.
I have no idea what I'm missing! thanks

The code:

button callback excerpt, from the main activity (seems to work)

```
// cb to put app to sleep until next round
    public void onDone(View view){
        Log.i(TAG, "onDone(). setting alarm");
        int i = 5;  // wake in 5 seconds
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, WakeupReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                this.getApplicationContext(), 234324243, intent, 0);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()
                + (i * 1000), pendingIntent);
    }
```

The receiver class: (executes ok)

```
public class WakeupReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = "INFO";

    MediaPlayer mp;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "WakeupReceiver running: ");
        mp=MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.wake);
        mp.start();
        Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
        Log.i(TAG, "...sent intent");
    }
}
```

My manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.xornot.pitch_exp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.PitchExperiment"
        >
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name="WakeupReceiver">
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to run an service with `service.startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification)` then your service will not be killed by Android System. And in the service register your `WakeupReceiver` and each time of `onReceive` you can call `startActivity` with context of `service`